# Design Pattern Help: How to render dynamic views from a single controller component?

Tags: design-patterns, reactjs

I current have a component that holds the business logic, depending on the page, I'd like to render different views. I'm having trouble since I'm not sure how to elegantly pass the functions and props of the control component into the view component.

Right now, my solution is:

```
<Controller viewComponent={ViewComponent} />
```

And then rendering inside Controller:

```
<this.props.viewComponent function1={this.func} function2={this.func2} />
```

It works, but it's confusing and I'm almost certain its not the most elegant solution. There's also a solution with cloning, but that seems like a hack too.

Does anybody have any insight into how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do:

`<Controller>
  <ViewComponent ... />
</Controller>`

And in Controller's render function:

`<div>
{this.props.children}
</div>`

Update: if you want to pass the parents functions and state/props to the children you use the React.Children.map func.

```
renderChildren = () => {
  React.Children.map(this.props.children, (c) => {
    <c.type
      {...this.props}
      {...c.props}
      someFunction={this.someFunction}
    />
  }
}

<div>
{ this.renderChildren() }
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is there's no way to pass the Controller's functions and state into the child. (Unless you use a clone, which I'd ideally like to avoid)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using something like [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router).  You can use react-router to perform client-sided routing that will render a different React component depending on the visited URL.

For example, this component will be used to define your routes and what components will be used to represent them:

**index.js**

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router';
import App from './app';
import Home from './home';
import Account from './account';

render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/account:username' component={Account}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

This component will be used to pass props (such as a list of functions) to any of the dynamically rendered components (rendered via `React.Children`):

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function getFunctionList() {
    return {
        someFunction() {
            //do something
        },
        someOtherFunction() {
            //do something
        }
    };
}

function renderComponent() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, ...getFunctionList())
    );
}

export default class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to={'/home'}>Home</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to={`/account/foo`}>foo's Account</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                {renderComponent.call(this)}
                <footer></footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

And here are some simple examples of components you'd be displaying to the user when the routes are visited:

**home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        //you could call this.props.someFunction() here
        return (
            <div className='home'>
                Home Page
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

**account.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class extends React.Component {
    const {username} = this.props.params;

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='account'>
                Viewing account for {username}
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

I really think your best bet is to do something like this.  Your problem sounds exactly like the kind of problem that react-router was built to solve.

If you wanted, you could extend this to use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) to keep track of a single `store` that can manage your application's state.  To keep it in sync with react-router, you could also use [this library](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux).

Let me know if you have any questions about these.